# Compare Object vs Dictionary<int,List<int>> considering performance c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, object

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Validator
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var metaValues = new List<Meta>
                    {
                        new Meta(4, 15, true),
                        new Meta(5, 20, false)
                    };

            var requestDict = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>
                    {
                      {4, new List<int>{15,20} },// error not exist 
                       {5, new List<int>{25} }, // error its false 
                       {6, new List<int>{30} }  // error not exist
                    };

            var matchedIds = new List<int>();

            if (metaValues.Any())
            {
                foreach (var ob in metaValues)
                {
                    if (requestDict.ContainsKey(ob.Id))
                    {
                        matchedIds.Add(ob.Id);
                        var valuesDict = requestDict[ob.Id];

                    //here i cant get all the values and its Active of meta.Id 

                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var key in requestDict.Keys)
            {
                if (!matchedIds.Contains(key))
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Meta
    {
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public int Value { get; private set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; private set; }

        public Meta(int id, int value, bool isActive)
        {
            Id = id;
            Value = value;
            IsActive = isActive;
        }


    }
}
```

iterating dictionary with object causing performance issue since everytime dictionary key has to be iterated in an list of object so i am trying to take object and lookup in dictionary on below condition

1. Invalid when meta.Id does not exist in dictionary key
2. Invalid when one of the meta.Value does not exist in dictionary values List
3. Inactive when meta.Id and meta.value match with dictionary but meta.isactive is false

Comment: Please fix the indenting so there's not so much horiontal scrolling!

Comment: Why make a class with the same name as a built-in type? It adds unnecessary confusion (in my opinion, anyway).

Comment: The posted code will not compile. Please update the question with the *actual* code.

Comment: What do you mean by "object properties"? Please explain the purpose of your code, ie. what did you *want* to do.

Comment: Note that `object` and `Object` are *NOT* the same thing in the code above.

Comment: As others have pointed out, your code does not compile. For instance, this: `var object =` is illegal because `object` is a reserved C# keyword. This means that it is almost certain that the code in your question is not the actual code you're having problems with. **Or**, the problems you're having with your code is completely different from your question. Please clear up the confusion by either restating the question, or posting the actual code.

Comment: You can't add items to a dictionary that have the same `Key` value (next to your comment *`// error since its not exist in object...`*).

Comment: sorry about my earlier post. i am still new and getting familiarize to post my questions. my apology . this is the compiled version . any help is much appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

I probably shouldn't bother answering since:

1. The code is quite messy
2. It does not compile
3. The question is very unclear

However, for some reason I feel like I understand a little what you're trying to do and wanted to provide some help.

First, let's NOT name a class with the same name as a built-in type (`System.Object`). Perhaps `Item` is generic enough? Also, you appear to instantiate instances of this class by calling a constructor that doesn't exist, so let's add that constructor as well:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public int Value { get; }
    public bool IsActive { get; }

    public Item(int id, int value, bool isActive)
    {
        Id = id;
        Value = value;
        IsActive = isActive;
    }
}
```

Now we can create our list of `Item` objects by calling the constructor:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item(4, 15, true),
    new Item(5, 20, false)
};
```

It also appears that you're creating a dictionary that contains a `Key` of type `int` that maps to `Item.Id`, and a `Value` of type `List<int>` that sort-of maps to `Item.Value` (though `Item.Value` is a single `int`). A problem in the code you posted is that you're trying to add two items with the same `Key` value of `4`, which is not legal for a `Dictionary` - all the keys must be unique. To fix this, I'm using unique keys:

```
var requests = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>
{
    {4, new List<int> {15}},
    {5, new List<int> {20}},
    {6, new List<int> {25}},
    {7, new List<int> {30}}
};
```

Next it appears that you're trying to create a `List<int>` of numbers representing the `Item.Id` values that exist as dictionary keys. This can be done with a `System.Linq` extension method:

```
var matchedIds = items
    .Where(item => requests.ContainsKey(item.Id))
    .ToList();
```

And finally, it's not exactly clear what you want to do with this list, but it appears you want to do something if either an `Item.Id` does not exist in the dictionary, or the `Item.Id` exists but the `Item.Value` is not in the list, or the item *does* exist, but the `Item.IsActive` value is `false`, or some other combination of these properties.

Here's how to get those items:

```
var matchedIds = items
    .Where(item => requests.ContainsKey(item.Id))
    .ToList();

var matchedIdsAndValues = matchedIds
    .Where(item => requests[item.Id].Contains(item.Value))
    .ToList();

var matchedIdsMissingValue = matchedIds
    .Where(item => !requests[item.Id].Contains(item.Value))
    .ToList();

var unmatchedIds = items
    .Where(item => !requests.ContainsKey(item.Id))
    .ToList();

var matchedIdAndValueButNotActive = matchedIdsAndValues
    .Where(item => !item.IsActive)
    .ToList();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the response. however i am having the same problem in linq too. here matchedIdsMissingValue  i want to return when requests has rows and not in matchedIds. can you help me on this as i am still trying to figure this out ? thanks in advance @Rufus L